# ColdFusion Datatable with SQL server Query

Tags: sql, ajax, coldfusion, datatables, coldfusion-9

I am trying to create a table with datatables and serverside pagination on a ColdFusion 9 server. The problem that I have is that when I create the query with an offset and limit for limiting the draw to only 100 results per page because the table has a unique value for the record and a unique value for the identification. In other words, I have a record `compname` with a unique id (specific to that `compname`) that can be alocated to 3 clients but with different data. I get only a limited number of records, because the offset and limit returns only the number of the records in the first 100 results of the query.

If I create the same query but in a table that has unique records, everything is working properly. Also if I don't use offset and limit I get the correct results but the loading time is very high because it returns the whole query.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

> Update 1

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

This is a sample of the query in the cfc:

```
<cfquery name="getdata" datasource="#data.dsn#" >
        WITH Rows AS
          (
SELECT  
  table1.unique_id,
  table1.Name,
  table2.data,
  table2.unique_id ,
  table2.data3,
  table2.data4,
  table2.data5,
  table2.data6,
  table2.data7,
  table2.data8,
  table2.data9,
  table3.data10,
  table3.data11,
  table3.data12,
  table3.data13,
  table3.data14,
  table4.data15,
  table4.data16,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY #sort#  #order# ) as [Row] 
FROM 
  (table1 
  inner join table2  
  on table1.unique_id=table2.unique_id)
  left join table3 on (table1.unique_id=table3.unique_id)
  left join table4 on (table1.unique_id=table4.unique_id)
  where table1.otherid= #clientid#
  and  table1.active=1
  <cfif Search NEQ ''>
  and (table1.unique_id like '%#arguments.Search#%' 
  OR table2.data like '%#arguments.Search#%' 
  )
```

```
)
  SELECT 
      *
  FROM
    Rows 
    where Row >= #offset + 1# and Row <= #offset + limit#
```

```
  <cfset resultStruct = Structnew() />
    <cfset resultStruct["rows"] = ArrayNew(1) />
    <cfset count = 1/>
    <cfoutput query="getdata" group="unique_id">
        <cfset resultStruct["rows"][count]['count'] =  count />
        <cfset resultStruct["rows"][count]['unique_id'] = getdata.unique_id 
  />
        <cfset resultStruct["rows"][count]['data'] =      getdata.data2 />
        <cfset resultStruct["rows"][count]['data2'] =     getdata.data3 />
        <cfset resultStruct["rows"][count]['data3'] =     getdata.data4 />
        <cfset resultStruct["rows"][count]['data4'] =     getdata.data5 />
        <cfset resultStruct["rows"][count]['data5'] =     getdata.data6 />
        <cfset resultStruct["rows"][count]['data6'] =     getdata.data7 />
        <cfset resultStruct["rows"][count]['data7'] =     getdata.data8 />
        <cfset resultStruct["rows"][count]['data8'] =     getdata.data9 />
        <cfset resultStruct["rows"][count]['data9'] =     getdata.data10 />
        <cfset resultStruct["rows"][count]['data10'] =     getdata.data11 />
        <cfset resultStruct["rows"][count]['data11'] =     getdata.data12 />

        <cfset COUNT = COUNT + 1/>
    </cfoutput>

    <cfreturn SerializeJSON(resultStruct) />
   </cffunction>
```

This is the datatable js

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#table1').bootstrapTable({
method: 'get',
url: 'test.cfc?method=getdata',
cache: false,
height: 700,
striped: true,
pagination: false,
pageList: [100, 200, 500],
rememberOrder:true,
deferRender: true,
serverside:true,
showColumns: true,
showRefresh: true,
paginationLoop:false,
clickToSelect: true,
sortName:"data",

columns: [
{field: 'count',title: 'No',sortable:true},
{field: 'unique_id',title: 'Unique ID',sortable:true},
{field: 'data',title: 'Data',align: 'center',valign: 'middle',sortable:true}, 
{field: 'data2',title: 'Sample Data',align: 'left',valign: 'top',sortable:true},
{field: 'data3',title: 'Sample Data',align: 'left',valign: 'top',sortable:true},
{field: 'data4',title: 'Sample Data',align: 'left',valign: 'top',sortable:true},
{field: 'data5',title: 'Sample Data',align: 'left',valign: 'top',sortable:true},
{field: 'data6',title: 'Sample Data',align: 'left',valign: 'top',sortable:true},
{field: 'data7',title: 'Sample Data',align: 'left',valign: 'top',sortable:true},
{field: 'data8',title: 'Sample Data',align: 'left',valign: 'top',sortable:true},
{field: 'data9',title: 'Sample Data',align: 'left',valign: 'top',sortable:true},
{field: 'data10',title: 'Sample Data',align: 'left',valign: 'top',sortable:true},
{field: 'data12',title: 'Sample Data',align: 'left',valign: 'top',sortable:true},
]


});

function getOrder() {
return $table.bootstrapTable('#table1').sortOrder 
=== 'desc' ? -1 : 1;
}

function numberSorter(a, b) {
if (!a) return -1 * getOrder();
if (!b) return 1 * getOrder();
if (a < b) return -1;
if (a > b) return 1;
return 0;
}

});
```

When I run this query i get only 30 results not 300 as normal..if i change the offset limit from 100 to 1500 i get back the full set of data. From my understanding when i use limit and offset the query is returning the table withing the limits. this works fine when you have data that is unique in the table.But i have duplicate data..for every client it can happen to have the same unique_id so for `clientid` 1 i have a record with unique id 100 which is in the first 100 rows in the db. but for client id 1 i can have a unique_id 299 which is in the next 499 rows.and when i run the query i get back for client id 1 only the unique_id's found in the first 100 rows in the db. if i don't use group in the output i get 100 results with duplicate unique_id from the first 100 rows.. so for unique_id 1 i get unique_id 1 - for clientid 1, unique_id 1 - from clientid 2 and so on. So, my main question is how can i create a query that in returning a small number of records without offset and limit..Hope that this covers everything.

Comment: Need more details with specific code example, expected output, and how the example code is not working. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: And what flavor and version of SQL.

Comment: .. in general, always include your dbms and version when posting a SQL question because syntax frequently varies by vendor.

Comment: You either have a DB query problem, or a Datatables problem. Verifty that the SQL statement returning what you need. `<cfdump>` can help with that. If SQL is good, then just work the Datatables side of things.

Comment: From the description only, it sounds likely to be a query problem. Run the query directly in SQL, hard coding the sort, offset and limit values. If you get the same results, it's really a SQL problem.

Comment: Yes, it is a query problem. When I run the SQL query and I do a 'cfdump' the results are the same.So, how can I re-create this query without the offset and limit but limit the number of rows returned, so I can improve the speed.The table has half a million records, and some of the clients have a couple of thousand and the table loads in 10 sec.I was hopping that Datatable with Side-server pagination will do the trick, but this seems to work only with tables that have unique records.I have the same configuration on different tables that have unique records and I don't have any problem

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "..can be alocated to 3 clients but with different data". It'll be much easier to help if you post ease post a (sanitized) sample of the data.

Comment: @ Ageax I mean that a company in the table, let's say Microsoft that has the unique id 100 can be found 3 times but with different data. For client 1 is Microsoft unique id 100 with a client reference test, for client 2 is MIcrosoft with unique id 100 with a client reference test2 and so on.I will post a sample of the data later on today.

Comment: You need to get your query returning the results you want to see in the datatable by grouping in the query rather than grouping the output in CF if your going to do the pagination in the query.